# How to add image file in Adobe AEM JCR using rest API from .Net

Tags: aem, jcr

I googled alot but not getting any documentation of Adobe AEM for restfull API. I tried the .Net code from 
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-net-client-application.html.
But it creates folder instead of uploading content.
What are the parameters we need to pass to upload any image, mp4, pdf etc. Below is my c# code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName=FileUpload1.FileName;

    String postURL = "http://localhost:4502/content/dam/geometrixx/" + fileName;

    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(postURL);
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");

    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.Credentials = nc;
    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (System.IO.Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

    string responseText = string.Empty;

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    TextBox1.Text = responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with .Net, but the question is more about how to create an asset in AEM. You didn't specify any version, so I tested my code only on AEM 5.6.1, but it should work also on AEM 6.X. In the following snippet you can see how you can upload new file using curl into a folder of your choice in dam, so you have only to make the call from your .Net code:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -F file=@"/absolute/path/to/your/file.ext" http://localhost:4502/content/dam/the/path/you/wish/to/upload/myfolder.createasset.html
```

You are sending a POST request to the dam path where the file have to be uploaded with the selector "createasset" and the extension "html".

Comment: I do not have provision to use curl. Is it possible to give an example to upload asset using simple javascript?

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with javascript and client side code execution. You can check [this link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax) if you still need to upload files through JS. What you ask for was how to use the AEM Rest API to upload your files and I think that I gave you everything you need. You have the url, the method and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

.net code for uploading files on Aem. Try below code.

```
var filelocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images\\YourFile with Extension";

FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filelocation);
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];

stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
stream.Close();


var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "Your Password"),
};

//var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    requestContent.Add(imageContent, "file", "file nmae with extension");


    var response1 = httpClient.PostAsync("http://siteDomain/content/dam/yourfolder.createasset.html", requestContent);
    var result = response1.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```